# React: programmatically change component value doesn't trigger onChange event

Tags: reactjs

I have one select field inside a React component, it value it's set through the component state an has an function attached to the onChange event. If I change the select field value manually, the onChange event it's triggered, but if I change it by changing the state value from another function it is not. It's there a way to trigger the event programmatically?

**Edit:**

Below is a basic example on what I need to achieve. The idea is that when the handleChange1() changes the value of state.val2 (and therefore change the option selected on the second select field) the handleChange2() is also triggered so the synthetic event is passed to the parent function (in the actual code, the select fields are another components):

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  state = {
    val1: 1,
    val2: 1,
  }

  handleChange1 = (event) => {
    const val2 = event.target.value === 3 ? 1 : null;
    this.setState({
      val1: event.target.value,
    });
    if (event.target.value === 3) {
      this.setState({
        val2: 1,
      });
    }
    this.props.parentFunction(event);
  }

  handleChange2 = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      val2: event.target.value,
    });
    this.props.parentFunction(event);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <select value={val1} onChange={this.handleChange1}>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
          </select>
          <select value={val2} onChange={this.handleChange2}>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Perhaps you could call the onChange handler from the other function changing the selects value

Comment: @Vincent: added!

Comment: What does the parentFunction does with the event?

Comment: Update the parent state using the event.target.name and event.target.value  and then dispatch a function that trigger an api call.
Important: this is just a basic example, the real code has a lot more generic field's component with different behaviors, that's why I don't want to add to much specific events handling. I just want they all end up sending the event to the parent and that the parent just need to extract the info it needs from the event.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a way! React has logic that prevents `onChange` from firing when an input's value is set programmatically, but it can be worked around.

Instead of:

```js
input.value = 'foo';
```

Do this:

```js
const setter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value').set;
setter.call(input, 'foo');
input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
```

Check out [this article](https://hustle.bizongo.in/simulate-react-on-change-on-controlled-components-baa336920e04) for the full explanation.

---

In case it's not clear, the value of `input` is the DOM element that you would get from a ref. Example:

```
function SomeComponent({ onChange }) {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      const input = ref.current;
      const setter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value').set;
      setter.call(input, new Date().toISOString());
      input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
    }, 10000);
  });

  return <input type="text" ref="ref" onChange={onChange} />;
}
```

This component would update its input with a date string & trigger the `onChange` callback with the new value every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your input in a dedicated component to customize the desired behavior. Something like :

```
class Input extends React.Component {

 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: props.value
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      value: nextProps.value,
    });
    this.props.onChange(nextProps.value);
  }

  updateValue(ev) {
    this.setState({
      value: ev.target.value,
    });
    this.props.onChange(ev.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        onChange={this.updateValue.bind(this)}
        value={this.state.value}
        {...this.props}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

and use it like:

```
<Input value="test" onChange={someAction} />
```

note that because your input is in a controlled state, value must never be null nor undefined.

Comment: Thanks, but in my code the select fields are already another component with behavior likes this. But I need the achieve the event triggering from the parent that contain it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fortunately **@gouroujo**'s answer works for me, but as I checked the documentation its name has changed to `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()` and docs say:

> #### Note
>
> This lifecycle was previously named **componentWillReceiveProps**. That name will continue to work until version 17. Use the [rename-unsafe-lifecycles codemod](https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod#rename-unsafe-lifecycles) to automatically update your components.

[More details about **UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()**](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key)

Another solution is to set a `key` on the component so that react can

> create a new component instance rather than update the current one.

[More details about **Fully uncontrolled component with a key**](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key)